# Show a notice when a question cannot be deleted through the mobile site

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, vote-to-delete

I try to delete a question on meta through the mobile site but it simply reloads and nothing happens. Then I switch to the full site and try again and see the following notice:

> Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead.

It is until then that I understand why nothing happens. Can you show this message on the mobile site as well, just like the one that shows up when you try to upvote your own question? It caused a little bit of confusion when the page just reloads.

Comment: Me too having same problem